# how to redirect to my template

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, templates

i hade create a new template in my plugin code

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'bogin_page_template', 99 );



function bogin_page_template( $template ) {


if ( is_page( 'bog_test' )  ) {
    $new_template = locate_template( array( 'bog_test.php' ) );
    if ( !empty( $new_template ) ) {
        return $new_template;
    }
}

return $template;


}
```

and i created a file bog_test.php in my plugin directory.
but when i go to http://bogss.co.il/bog_test/ 
it says page not found. 
what am i missimg here ? thank you !

Comment: Have you actually created a page called 'bog_test'?

Comment: yes, in the same dir as my plugin.php file(duffrent name for the plugin file..)

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense. Pages aren’t files in plugins or themes. They’re added in the WordPress backend. Also, locate_template won’t work for a template file in a plugin. It searches themes.

Comment: ok, so how can i add a page to a store with a plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you  can overwrite `get_page_template()` using  `page_template` filter.
So now, your code should be like bellow code.

```
   add_filter( 'page_template', 'load_template_from_plugin' );
   function load_template_from_plugin( $page_template ){
        if ( is_page( 'bog_test' ) ) {
            $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/bog_test.php';
        }
        return $page_template;
    }
```

Try the above code then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: ok, so i paste it in my plugin code, and then did some stuff with the plugin to make sure it run's the code, but still the resuls is "page not found.
so i tried http://bogss.co.il/bog_test.php
and http://bogss.co.il/bog_test/
both not good. what am i miising here? mybe the bog_test.php need somting to be wirtten in it ?