# how to add a page to a plugin?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, pages

Im trying to add a page programmatically to a store by installing my plugin. 
I tried to create a template but it seems to be the wrong way.
can someone help ? `thanks`
I DO DONT need a tamplate, i need to add a page to my store.

**EDIT**
I had created a page with

```
$title = __( 'Bogin' );
if ( NULL == get_page_by_title( $title ) ) {
$post_id = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'post_name'      => 'bogin',
        'post_title'     => $title,
        'post_content'   => "some content",
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
    )
);
```

and now i can controll the content of that page use html & javascript.
Im planing to put a relly big file in there.
am I need an other way to do so? 
can I change the size of the file 'page_content' in table 'wp_post' by code ? 
i would like to find a way to do it by code beacuse that when i save a big string there the site creashed

Comment: This is the third time you’ve asked this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to redirect to my template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303623/how-to-redirect-to-my-template)

Comment: in that question I asked about a template

Comment: You’re clearly asking how to do the same thing 3 different ways.

Comment: Im cleary need help, but no, I andersted to ask about page insted of template from the comments, YOU r clearly dont want to help, so why interrupt ?

Comment: @JacobPeattie if you see that I am asking the same thing, can you tell me how to ask it ? do you anderstend what Im looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the activation hook and call function wp_insert_post()

```
class MyPlugin {
    static function install() {
        $my_post = [
            'post_title'    => 'My page title',
            'post_content'  => 'My page content',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1, // Set author id here
            'post_type'     => 'page',
        ];
        wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, [ 'MyPlugin', 'install' ] );
```